# artisan flag to open up the server in the browser

Tags: php, browser, laravel-artisan

In many frameworks, there are flags such as `--open` in `ng serve --open` for angular which serves an angular application and opens the URL in the default browser. **Is there any flag to be used along with the `php artisan serve` command to do the same?** It seems there is no such a flag, If am right, what technical reasons or challenges would be there to have this?

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 8, there is no built-in flag to open the served application in the default browser. This is because Laravel is a server-side framework, and the php artisan serve command is used to start a local development server to serve your application.

Opening the URL in the default browser is typically handled by the operating system or a separate application, rather than the framework or programming language. For example, in Windows, you can use the start command to open a URL in the default browser, like this:

```
start http://localhost:8000
```

Alternatively, you can use a browser extension or a separate command-line tool to open the URL in the default browser.

In summary, while there is no built-in flag to open the served application in the default browser in Laravel, there are other ways to achieve this using operating system commands, browser extensions, or command-line tools.

Comment: Seems logical, any reference to the fact you made "As of Laravel 8 ....."?